# how get react router origin url without params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to origin url path without router params.

```
// routers
<Route
  exact
  path={`/users/userDetail/:userId`}
  component={UserDetail}
/>

i want to get string "/users/userDetail" from some components
```

help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the path of the current route, while excluding the last `userId` part of the URL - assuming that's the case, you could do the following:

```
const getCurrentPathWithoutLastPart = () => {

    return location.pathname.slice(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))
}
```

If your current URL is something like `/users/userDetail/some_value` calling the function will yield `/users/userDetail`:

```
getCurrentPathWithoutLastPart() // returns /users/userDetail
```

Answer (score 8):

You can exclude all params from current pathname by using this hook:

```
import { useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const useBasePath = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const params = useParams<Record<string, string>>();

    return Object.values(params).reduce(
        (path, param) => path.replace('/' + param, ''),
        location.pathname,
    );
};
```

Use it like this in your component:

```
const basePath = useBasePath();

console.log(basePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Alecu Marian Alexandru does work for most routes but fails for a special case. If you got a path parameter that is a substring of the route path like:

```
/category/cat
```

you'll get

```
egory/cat
```

I fixed this by deconstructing the "path parameter string" and "location.pathname string" into arrays and filtering out every path parameter from the location.pathname array:

```js
    export function useRoutePath()
    {
       const location = useLocation();
       const params = useParams<Record<string, string>>()["*"]?.split("/").filter(param => param.length);
       const pathElements = location.pathname.split("/").filter(element => element.length && !params?.includes(element));
       return "/" + pathElements.join("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing solution is helpful, but it doesn't work for all scenarios. For example, we can't use it for the parent pathname as it will return empty string.

Adding to the existing solution:

```
const getCurrentPathWithoutLastPart = () => {
    const pathRgx = /\//g;
    const childroutecount = ((location.pathname || '').match(pathRgx) || []).length
    return childroutecount > 1 ? location.pathname.slice(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')) : location.pathname;
}
```